# Which one is correct for the form of noun?

Tags: grammar, nouns

1. His and my computer are in good condition.
2. His and my computers are in good condition.

Note that there are two computers, one belongs to me, and the other belongs to him. I am confusing whether I should use "computers" or "computer" in the above sentence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["They're using a cell phone" vs. "They're using cell phones"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/theyre-using-a-cell-phone-vs-theyre-using-cell-phones) Although the distributive singular should never be dismissed as incorrect per se ("Girls, assuming you're right-handed, holding your protractor down with your left hand, take your pencil in your right hand and ..."), in this example, ' ... [my] computer are ...' sounds unnecessarily jarring.

Comment: @Lawrence Wrong candidate for duplicate.

Comment: We still don't have a canonical answer for distributed one-for-one possessions? There was a question about *everybody take a seat/ everybody take their seats* that I though covered this.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107431/i-am-so-confused-by-for-example-people-love-their-life-or-lives